# Foreign key constraint on Prisma model creation

Tags: typescript, database, orm, prisma

I have a create user function in my `user.server.ts`:

```
export async function createUser(username: User["username"], email: User["email"], password: string) {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

  const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email,
      username,
      role: {
        create: {
          name: ValidRoles["User"]
        }
      },
      hashed_password: hashedPassword,
    },
  })

  return prisma.userProfile.create({
    data: {
       user: {
        connect: user
       },
       userId: user.id,
    }
  })
}
```

This adheres to this Schema:

```
model User {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  username String @unique @default("user")
  email    String    @unique
  hashed_password String
  role     Role      @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id]) // Fields: PK, references: FK
  roleId   Int       @default(0)
  
  profile UserProfile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade)
  profileId Int @unique @default(1)
  
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt
}

model UserProfile {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user User?
  userId Int @unique
}
```

When I register a new user, however, I get this error:

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation in
app\models\user.server.ts:18:34

  15 export async function createUser(username: User["username"], email: User["email"], password: string) {
  16   const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
  17 
→ 18   const user = await prisma.user.create(
Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `User_profileId_fkey (index)`
    at Zr.handleRequestError (node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:171:6414)
    at Zr.handleAndLogRequestError (node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:171:5948)
    at Zr.request (node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:171:5786)
    at t._request (node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:174:10455)
    at createUser (app\models\user.server.ts:18:16)
    at action (app\routes\register.tsx:26:9)
    at Object.callRouteActionRR (build\server.js:39464:20)
    at callLoaderOrAction (build\server.js:38586:18)
    at submit (build\server.js:38277:20)
    at queryImpl (build\server.js:38240:27)
```

I assumed my relations were correct, and if they aren't if someone could elaborate that'd be great. Otherwise, if not, what is wrong and how do I remedy this? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
profile UserProfile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade)
profileId Int @unique @default(1)
```

Well you have `profileId` as `NOT NULL` with a default of `1`. If you don't have a `UserProfile` with an `id` of `1`, then the database won't like that id pointing at a non-existent record.

Maybe you should make that a nullable reference like:

```
profileId Int? @unique
```

Comment: Good catch. This makes sense. Thank you! I'm a front end dev fairly new to the backend world so this helps a ton.

Comment: Is there a way to create the profileId as soon as a User is created?

Comment: Well you just create the child relation first. `const profile = await prisma.userProfile.create(...); await prisma.user.create({ data: { profileId: profile.id, ... } })`